# run out of input

Tags: python

I have used pickle.dumps to create a binary file after i generated a Huffman tree, but now I can't load the file and i don't understand the error message:
line 5, in 
tree = pickle.load(file_handle)
EOFError: Ran out of input

```
import pickle
from compress import node
with open("binary.bin", "rb") as file_handle:
    data = pickle.load(file_handle)
    tree = pickle.load(file_handle)
```

this is the code to create the binary file:

```
import pickle
q = {}
a_file = open("george.txt", 'r')
for line in a_file:
    key, value = line.split()

    q[key] = value


class node:
    def __init__(self, freq, symbol, left=None, right=None):
        self.freq = freq

        self.symbol = symbol

        self.left = left

        self.right = right

        self.huff = ''


def printNodes(node, val=''):
    newVal = val + str(node.huff)
    if(node.left):
        printNodes(node.left, newVal)
    if(node.right):
        printNodes(node.right, newVal)

    if(not node.left and not node.right):
        print(f"{node.symbol} -> {newVal}")


chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

freq = [q['a'], q['b'], q['c'], q['d'], q['e'], q['f']]

nodes = []

for x in range(len(chars)):
    nodes.append(node(freq[x], chars[x]))

while len(nodes) > 1:
    nodes = sorted(nodes, key=lambda x: x.freq)

    left = nodes[0]
    right = nodes[1]
    left.huff = 0
    right.huff = 1
    newNode = node(left.freq+right.freq, left.symbol+right.symbol, left, right)
    nodes.remove(left)
    nodes.remove(right)
    nodes.append(newNode)

with open('binary.bin', 'wb') as f:
    b = pickle.dumps(nodes[0])
    f.write(b)
```

Comment: `load`, not `loads`, is the one that takes a file object.

Comment: Also there's no way the error message would say TextIOWrapper if you opened the file in binary mode.

Comment: when i try load i am getting this error AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'node' on <module '__main__'

Comment: That's a separate issue, and requires a new question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should show us code that can create *a* `binary.bin` from scratch *that causes the problem*, even if it's much simpler than the one you actually have.

Comment: i edited the post with the code to create the binary.bin

Comment: Of course you get "ran out of input".  The first `pickle.load` used up all the input and left the file at end of file.  Why are you trying to get two copies of it, anyway?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky, and is described in the documentation.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

Remember that the unpickle process has to recreate the objects that you pickled.  It can only do that if it can find the original classes.  Otherwise, your objects won't have any methods.  If `class node` is defined in your main module, or if you have `from module import node`, then it should unpickle just fine.  But, for example, if you have a class that pickles itself, then pickle doesn't know what module the class came from, so it can't find the class to recreate the object.

Comment: Class? Node? What are you talking about?

Comment: @georgederderian You mean you completely changed the entire question, and Tim knew in advance what you would change it to? What is going on?....

Comment: i think he just read the comments because i said that when i put load the error is from class node

Comment: @georgederderian That wasn't even true, you were using `loads`, which didn't even *attempt* to do anything with the file handle you gave it, *that* was the error.

Comment: in the comments i said that when i try load i am getting this error AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'node' on <module 'main'